# Cordova Plugin Apprate not define.

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Im trying to Test my ionic App but every-time i serve it i get a blank screen and navbar. I get an error that looks like this ive spent countless hours looking but yet nothing.

```
`Uncaught ReferenceError: AppRate is not defined
    at Object.setPreferences (ng-cordova.min.js:7)
    at Array.<anonymous> (config.js:24)
    at onPlatformReady (ionic.bundle.js:2496)
    at onWindowLoad (ionic.bundle.js:2477)`

        angular.module("ngCordova.plugins.appRate", []).provider("$cordovaAppRate", [function() {
        this.setPreferences = function(e) {
            e && angular.isObject(e) && (AppRate.preferences.useLanguage = e.language || null,
            AppRate.preferences.displayAppName = e.appName || "",
            AppRate.preferences.promptAgainForEachNewVersion = e.promptForNewVersion || !0,
            AppRate.preferences.openStoreInApp = e.openStoreInApp || !1,
            AppRate.preferences.usesUntilPrompt = e.usesUntilPrompt || 3,
            AppRate.preferences.useCustomRateDialog = e.useCustomRateDialog || !1,
            AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.ios = e.iosURL || null,
            AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.android = e.androidURL || null,
            AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.blackberry = e.blackberryURL || null,
            AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.windows8 = e.windowsURL || null)
        }
```

This is the error i get everytime i serve my app via ionic CLI. I've tried updating the plugins and yet nothing please help. This is my ionic info:

```
 global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Gulp CLI         : not installed globally
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp    : 1.0.1
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1  : 2.0.0
    Cordova Platforms         : android 5.1.1 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework           : ionic1 1.3.1

System:

    Node       : v7.4.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
    ios-deploy : 1.9.1
    ios-sim    : 6.0.0
    npm        : 4.0.5
```

Comment: Are you running it in the browser?

Comment: Yes, But i also put it up on Test flight and tried to test it on my phone and still nothing shows up. but the navbar @robbannn

Answer (score 1):

Makes sure all your calls to the plugin happen after the cordova onDeviceReady event has fired.
For Ionic, You should move your code inside the $ionicPlatform.ready() callback.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 
  if(window.cordova){
    AppRate.preferences.displayName = "MyApp"
    AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {
      ios: '<my_app_id>',
      android: 'market://details?id=my_app_id'
    };
  }
});
```